# Wechat Integration with Drupal

Tags: drupal, wechat

I am trying to implement WeChat with my Druplal application. I am not able to get the WeChat appID, How to get weChat APP ID?

HTTP request method: GET
https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/token?grant_type=client_credential&appid=APPID&secret=APPSECRET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to http://dev.wechat.com/ create an application and get APPID and APPSECRET.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/wechat， here is a Drupal module for it.

Answer (score 0):

regist a account on https://mp.weixin.qq.com/ , then you can have the app_id and app_serect.

The difficulty for you is how to activate the account... because wechat is belongs to Tencent in china, before activate some company profile needs to be provided, and the qualified company profile should come from "a chinese compmay"....

any way I have developed a lot wechat platform application....
if you have any further question, you may @me